# Third level domain and redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a domain like mydomain.com
I have bought blog.mydomain.com

I want that when people hit blog.mydomain.com, they get redirected to mydomain.com/blog.

What I am trying is the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/blog$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works, but trouble is, if I check blog.mydomain.com/some-content-that-belongs-to-mydomain I want it to also redirect to www.mydomain.com/blog.

Instead, what it does is to effectively "duplicate" my content that is available both at mydomain.com/stuff and at blog.mydomain.com/stuff

Hope it's clear enough, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. Do you mean that if someone types `blog.example.com/foo`, it should be redirected to `www.example.com/blog` instead of `www.example.com/blog/foo`?

Comment: to add to Jenny D, is it bad that your latest blog post is available at `blog.mydomain.com/latest` and `www.mydomain.com/blog/latest`? You are not actually creating two places, you are just sending them to the correct place if they hit the wrong one.

Comment: Yes the issue being that at www.mydomain.com I has some content which is not related to my blog. So if you type blog.pazienti.it/some-content-available-only-on-mydomain-com you should be redirected to blog.mydomain.com

Comment: @JennyD yes exactly